# Flexibility of C++'s constexpr if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

I often come across this situation:

```
if (A && B)
{
    C();
}
else
{
    D();
}
```

But when `A` is `constexpr`, there is no way to indicate that to the if statement if `B` is not also `constexpr`.
Further, the workaround for enabling use of `constexpr` is ugly:

```
if constexpr (A)
{
    if (B)
    {
        C();
    }
    else
    {
        D();
    }
}
else
{
    D();
}
```

Is there a proposal to make `constexpr if` statements more flexible ie. to consider which of the conditionals are `constexpr`?
And if not, is there a workaround for this situation other than assuming the compiler will do the right thing (which they don't always do).

Comment: Dispatch via function pointers maybe?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you think the compiler does the wrong thing?

Comment: No, there is no proposal. And there is no workaround. And I doubt that it's likely there will ever be. Due to the fundamentally different semantics of `if constexpr`, it is unwise to make something like this be derived indirectly; and it's something that should always be explicitly indicated.

Comment: Why so pessimistic about compilers, if A is constexpr, then even without `if constexpr`, the optimised assembly won't look much different.

Comment: @Mansoor, no, that's not the case in all cases.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, The rules for constexpr functions in C++20 allow for flexibility of calling between runtime and compiletime. I see no reason why this would not be implemented in the future, being familiar with the standards committee.

Comment: @cigien it is pretty common for compilers of various types (MSVC, GCC) to not compile-time evaluate code which's not explicitly marked as constexpr. I've done the before-and-after tests, seen the file size reduction and don't personally feel a need to provide examples. But if you want specific examples, earlier versions of GCC did not optimize out is_trivially_destructible calls-

Comment: @metamorphosis: "*The rules for constexpr functions in C++20 allow for flexibility of calling between runtime and compiletime.*" But functions are the *only* place where such flexibility exists. In every other place where `constexpr` is allowed, the standard *means it*. `if constexpr`, `constexpr` variables, etc. The oddball out is functions, which is why C++20 gave us `consteval` functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes. well aware of that, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`if constexpr` is not "faster `if`". It's not the `if` statement you use when a conditional expression happens to be a constant expression. It's not even the `if` statement you use when you want the compiler to test the condition at compile time (compilers are capable of doing that on their own).

The meaning of the `if constexpr` usage in your second example is that the expression `C()` is not meant to be *valid C++* unless the condition represented by `A` is true. This is *why* you guard a code block with `if constexpr`; this is why the feature was added to the language to begin with. Obviously you can use it for other things, but if all you care about is getting the compiler to evaluate a condition expression at compile-time, you shouldn't be using `if constexpr`.

And it is for this reason why what you're asking for is not forthcoming.

Looking at your second example, the difficulties in replicating `if constexpr`'s behavior across an expression that is only partially a constant expression become apparent. The rules would need a fair bit of complexity. In your example, `D()` must be valid C++ code even if `A` is true, since `B` could be false at runtime.

You'd need to build some fairly complex rules about how such "partial constexpr" expressions prohibit the evaluation of the various code branches. And that can easily lead to difficulty in users understanding when a complex expression will cull out which branches and when it won't.

Better to just make users write it out long-form in these cases.

Comment: The problem is that compilers aren't capable of evaluating which statements are compile-time and which aren't. Ideally they would be, but they don't always. See my responses to the comments on the question.
I take your point that code which isn't accessible due to constexpr A being false would not be evaluated at compile-time. However that doesn't affect the situation I'm describing - both || and && are easily usable in this situation. && means if A is false, the expression is false and isn't evaluated. || means if A is false it becomes a runtime 'if' based on B, otherwise compile-time.

Comment: @metamorphosis: "*The problem is that compilers aren't capable of evaluating which statements are compile-time and which aren't.*" Capable is the wrong word; a compiler has all of the knowledge it needs to do it. Choosing not to is not a lack of capability. In any case, this is too much of a micro-optimization to bother writing a whole language feature for. In the few instances where a compiler fails to optimize a constexpr condition away in hot code, you can detect this and restructure your code accordingly. But only after your profiler tells you that you need those cycles in that location.

Comment: @metamorphosis: "*I'm not appreciating the level of angst I'm getting from your writing.*" I'm not exhibiting any "angst", so I don't know where that's even coming into play. And yes, I read your comments, and my point still applies. From your comments, you care about this because "it is pretty common for compilers of various types (MSVC, GCC) to not compile-time evaluate code which's not explicitly marked as constexpr". The only reason to care about this is *performance*, and my point is that this is a micro-optimization for which a dedicated feature is not warranted.

Comment: Yeah whatever mate

Answer (score 0):

> is there a workaround for this situation other than assuming the compiler will do the right thing (which they don't always do).

Well... when the code in your example is *all* the content of a `void` function (or a final part of a `void` function)... what about something as follows?

```
if constexpr ( A )
   if ( B )
    {
      C();

      return;
    }

D();
```

Otherwise (if your code is a not-final fragment of a bigger function), I suppose you can wrap it in a `while`

```
while ( 1 )
 {
   if constexpr ( A )
      if ( B )
       {
         C();

         break;
       }

   D();

   break;
 }
```

but I suppose this is a "assuming the compiler will do the right thing" case.